# Debugging broken connection with EC2, Ubuntu, & Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-server

After following [this tutorial](http://ericwconner.com/?p=347) to setup an EC2 instance for a Django app, I can't connect to the application. Any help debugging, would be greatly appreciated.

Steps followed after setting up EC2 instance:

1. sudo aptitude install python-django
2. sudo aptitude install mysql-server
3. sudo aptitude install python-mysqldb
4. sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi
5. mkdir srv
6. cd srv
7. django-admin startproject mysite
8. sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com

   ```
   NameVirtualHost *:80

   <VirtualHost *:80>

       ServerName mysite.com
       ServerAlias www.mysite.com
       WSGIScriptAlias / /home/demo/public_html/mysite.com/mysite.wsgi
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
9. sudo vim /home/demo/public_html/mysite.com/mysite.wsgi

   ```
   import os
   import sys

   sys.path.append('/home/demo/public_html/mysite.com/')

   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

   import django.core.handlers.wsgi

   application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
   ```
10. sudo a2ensite mysite.com
11. sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

For my host records on my URL:

```
    @  to the Private IP from Amazon as an A Record
    www to the Private IP from Amazon as an A record
```

The result is that when I enter the IP address, myurl.com, and www.myurl.com all are unable to connect to the server.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the private IP for your instance, that's only useful if you're accessing your instance from *within* EC2, instead use the public IP in your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an elastic IP attached to the instance for a static, public IP address.  You then place this in your host file. These are free as long as you have them attached to an *active* instance.  If you terminate or stop the instance, you will be billed for it.